# What is the SASS equivalent to *= require_self and *= require_tree .?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, spree

I am trying to solve a problem in my Rails 4 + Spree app and a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723991/override-spree-commerces-bootstrap-variables) suggested me to convert my all.css file to all.scss (sass).

How do I convert

```
*= require spree/frontend
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

to @imports?

I did the

```
@import "spree/frontend";
```

Which was pretty straightforward, but now my app is "unstyled" and I am positive it is because of the other two directives.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to import a whole directory in sass using @import?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778627/is-it-possible-to-import-a-whole-directory-in-sass-using-import)

Answer (score 9):

'require_tree' will tell asset pipeline to include all the files within the specified directory. By default it is set to current directory with . (i,e dot). Refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html for more details.

After changing the filename of *application.css* to *application.scss*, `\*=require_tree .` can be replaced with `@import "/\*"` (Example:- on a mac the statement would be translated to a path something like `/Users/user_name/app_name/app/assets/stylesheets/*`) . The `*` here imports all the files within the stylesheets directory. Refer to [Is it possible to import a whole directory in sass using @import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778627/is-it-possible-to-import-a-whole-directory-in-sass-using-import) for more information.

This should solve your problem.

But, the suggested way to go about this is to create another file with a .scss extension that contains all the imports you want and use `\*=require_self` and `\*=require_tree .` within the `application.scss` file.